# Itext - reader.NumberOfPages returning - 1 - wrong page count

Tags: pdf, adobe, itext, livecycle-designer

I am working on this pdf,
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1095c--2015.pdf. 
It's a 3 page - Acro pdf form

I open this pdf in Adobe Live Cycle designer, which suggests to make this document as flowable interactive form. As per my understanding it converts this acro form to XFA, then I save it as Dynamic (it also has a option of static), but I need to fill this form multiple times. Now, in my itextSharp project, when I try to get count of pages in pdf,

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
int formPageCount = reader.NumberOfPages; //its returns 1 (wrong)
reader.Close();
```

This returns count as 1(wrong). When I open PDF in normal Adobe pdf reader, in properties, it shows number of pages as 3(correct).

Any ideas on why itext is not returning a correct page count? Same code works for original copy of form and returns 3(correct).

Comment: Just a long shot before the experts jump in: A dynamic XFA form is built up dynamically when it is opened in a XFA-capable viewer. In a non-XFA-capable viewer (which I assume the iText component is), you will always see one single page. (but I am sure someone from iText will jump in).

Comment: @MaxWyss is correct. If you view the actual code for the PDF you'll see that there is literally just one single page with the text _If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF  viewer may not be able to display this type of document._

Comment: @Max *In a non-XFA-capable viewer (which I assume the iText component is)* - strictly speaking iText is not a *viewer* at all. It does not display anything. On the other hand it is partially XFA-capable, in particular it can set certain types of XFA fields. Most of the API, though, works on the standard PDF structure, e.g. the `NumberOfPages` property.

Comment: @mkl: I did use the term "viewer" indeed in a very broad sense. "Reader" might be better, but that would create even more confusion with an actual product.

Comment: Note that iText's XFA worker can *flatten* a PDF, meaning that it converts the XML inside the template to regular PDF syntax (removing all interactivity). Once this is done, you'll see that the resulting PDF has more pages (or not, depending on the data that was added).

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie , thanks for replying, flattening of form provides me with correct count.  so, no way to read correct count of pages of dynamic XFA form without flattening?

Comment: You can answer that question yourself: suppose that you have an XML file full of data. How do you know how many pages that XML file will have when you render it? You can only know that *after* you've rendered it, can't you? The same goes for a dynamic XFA form. In a dynamic XFA form, there is very little PDF syntax. The PDF is merely a container for the XML. Only when you render the XML to PDF, you know how many pages are needed to present all the data.

Comment: And slightly different question - See my form https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1095c--2015.pdf

I filled this form with 3 records(expects 9 pages)  using FillXfaForm data- it produced 7 pages, instead of 9 pages. As it did not repeat the 2nd page on flattening. As 2nd page had no form fillable fields, is there a way to change this behavior? With 9 pages I can standardize my collation logic. I can create a separate thread if you want.